# How do I resolve apt GPG error NO_PUBKEY?

Tags: 12.04, apt

I do not recall why I have download.opensuse.org, but I am OK just removing whatever is causing this error:

```
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6FE3AE1CC7D68E37
```

This does not appear to be a duplicate question because the solutions proposed in other similar questions are not working here:

```
# sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 6FE3AE1CC7D68E37
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.OCmHCQ908W --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 6FE3AE1CC7D68E37
gpg: requesting key C7D68E37 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: key 6FE3AE1CC7D68E37 not found on keyserver
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

I'm on 12.04

Answer (score 0):

I had overlooked this entry in sources.list:

```
deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:ksmanis/xUbuntu_12.04/ /
```

Removing that line is the answer I was looking for.

However, upon finding that entry, I was able to find the reason it was there and a better fix:

How To Install GRUB2 Editor 0.6.4 On Ubuntu 13.04, 12.04, Linux Mint 15, 13, Elementary OS 0.2, Pear OS 8, Debian 7, 6 | LinuxG.net
http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-grub2-editor-0-6-4-on-ubuntu-13-04-12-04-linux-mint-15-13-elementary-os-0-2-pear-os-8-debian-7-6/

```
$ sudo sed -i '$ a\deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:ksmanis/xUbuntu_12.04/ /' /etc/apt/sources.list
$ wget -q http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:ksmanis/xUbuntu_12.04/Release.key -O- | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install kcm-grub2
```